# pygame, load .wav file memory error

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote the code in `conf.py` file

```
env_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('resources/sound/env.wav')
```

And in `game.py` file, I just `import conf`

```
env_sound = conf.env_sound
```

The error is

```
File "/path/game.py", line 8, in <module>
    import conf
File "/path/conf.py", line 45, in <module>
    env_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('resources/sound/env.wav')

MemoryError
```

The `game.py` and `conf.py` are in the same directory.

The size of `env.wav` is just about 511 kB, and I think it couldn't cause memory error.

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to init the `pygame.mixer` to make it work. So something along the line of:

```
#add this somewhere before env_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('resources/sound/env.wav')
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)
```

Read the [pygame doc](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) for further reference.